# PHP mailer query

Tags: php

So I am using and successfully sending emails out using PHPmailer yet once the email sends I am not sure where to put the page redirect back to the page you came from with a message saying message sent perhaps?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['hp']) && $_POST['hp'] && $_POST['hp'] != '') {    

}

else {

require 'c:\php\includes\PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port =;

$mail->From = '';
$mail->FromName = '';


foreach ($members as $user) {

$mail->addAddress($user->user_email);  

}

foreach ($committee as $user) {

$mail->AddCC($user->user_email);  

}





$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_POST["Subject"];
$mail->Body    = $_POST["contentfield"];





if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;

}
}

?>
```

I have taken all my details out for obvious reasons.

Comment: Are you just asking how to redirect the user from PHP code?  Does all of this mailer code (which you say works as expected) really have anything to do with this?

Comment: Hi, Yep the problem being that when I include a redirect such as header(Location) it stops sending out the email for some reason.

Comment: In that case it sounds like there *is* an error somewhere.  Can you show the code which causes this error?  When you debug, where does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add an else to your `if()` mail doesn't send statement and redirect the user if the if statement does not fail?

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;

} else {
  // email sent successfully, redirect to success page
  header ('Location: sent.php');
}
```

Your email should still send because the browser will only redirect you if `$mail->send()` evaluates to true... and at this point the mail has already sent.

You could also put the redirect after the `if()` statement if you wanted to and that should also work because if your `if()` statement evaluates to true it will exit the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can send HTTP redirects in PHP  using the location header:

```
<?php
header('Location: /path/to/page');
exit;
```

Comment: When I included that it stopped sending the email, perhaps I put this in the wrong place?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you are asking where to put the redirect, as opposed to how to actually do the redirect. Just place the redirect at the bottom of this script. The line that sends the e-mail is the one containing `$mail->send()`. Anywhere after that line (and outside the last conditional block) will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to have a redirect. You could just return a `204 No Content` and the browser wil stay where it is. If you want to return a status code, you could pass the result in the redirect as a param, redirect to a different page, or stick a value in the session, ready to display on the next page. Something like:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    header('Location: failed.php?error='.rawurlencode($mail->ErrorInfo));
}
    header('Location: success.php');
}
```